# How to print an Array in reverse order (from end to beginning) separating with comma

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

The task is like in the title. I tried to wrote a code but something is going wrong and the output is bad. How to fix it?

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Hometask4ReverseArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arrayNames = {"Sam", "Sara", "Tim", "Bob", "Kate"};
        Arrays.sort(arrayNames, Collections.<String>reverseOrder());
        for(int i = 0; i < arrayNames.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(arrayNames[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:
TimSaraSamKateBob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working as expected. The reverseOrder() means alphabetically reverse.

If you need to print from the last to the first the solution is more simple, you don't need to sort:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arrayNames = {"Sam", "Sara", "Tim", "Bob", "Kate"};

    for(int i = arrayNames.length-1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        System.out.print(arrayNames[i] + (i != 0 ? + "," : ""));
    }
}
```

As you can see I have used a contract if (or ternary operator) to add comma only if `i` counter's value is different from 0

Comment: Could you plz tell me how to make commas between names. The output is  KateBobTimSaraSam